# Error installing Laravel on Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install laravel in opt/lampp/htdocs directory and get this error:

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.3.16)


[ErrorException]            
mkdir(): Permission denied  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it with`sudo`

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: but in said Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Comment: change the directory that you are working on, so you can do it without using sudo